# Nested useFetch cause Hydration node mismatch in Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, pinia

Inside a Nuxt 3 page, I fetch post data by calling an action from a pinia store:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="postData && postContent">
    {{ postData }}
    {{ postContent }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
const config = useRuntimeConfig()
const route = useRoute()
const slug = route.params.slug
const url = config.public.wpApiUrl
const contentStore = useContentStore()

await contentStore.fetchPostData({ url, slug })

const postData = contentStore.postData
const postContent = contentStore.postContent
</script>
```

That's my store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useContentStore = defineStore('content',{
    state: () => ({
        postData: null,
        postContent: null
    }),
    actions: {
        async fetchPostData({ url, slug }) {
            try {
                const { data: postData, error } = await useFetch(`${url}/wp/v2/posts`, {
                    query: { slug: slug },
                    transform(data) {
                        return data.map((post) => ({
                            id: post.id,
                            title: post.title.rendered,
                            content: post.content.rendered,
                            excerpt: post.excerpt.rendered,
                            date: post.date,
                            slug: post.slug,
                        }));
                    }
                })
                this.postData = postData.value;
                if (postData && postData.value && postData.value.length && postData.value[0].id) {
                    const {data: postContent} = await useFetch(`${url}/rl/v1/get?id=${postData.value[0].id}`,
                        {
                            method: 'POST',
                        });
                    this.postContent = postContent.value;
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching post data:', error)
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The output in the browser is fine, but I get the following error in browser console:

```
entry.js:54 [Vue warn]: Hydration node mismatch:
- rendered on server: <!---->  
- expected on client: div 
  at <[slug] onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <Anonymous key="/news/hello-world()" vnode= {__v_isVNode: true, __v_skip: true, type: {…}, props: {…}, key: null, …} route= {fullPath: '/news/hello-world', hash: '', query: {…}, name: 'news-slug', path: '/news/hello-world', …}  ... > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <Default ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <LayoutLoader key="default" layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} name="default" > 
  at <NuxtLayoutProvider layoutProps= {ref: RefImpl} key="default" name="default"  ... > 
  at <NuxtLayout> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

How can I fix this issue?

I tried to fetch post data within onMounted but in this case postData and postContent stay null

```
onMounted(async () => {
  await contentStore.fetchPostData({ url, slug })
})
```

Comment: you say nested `useFetch` which suggests a `useFetch` inside a `useFetch` - i don't see such code in what you posted - perhaps I'm misinterpreting what you mean by `nested`

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, maybe the title is misleading. in this case i mean that the second useFetch needs a value from the first useFetch response as parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClientOnly` component to get rid of that warning. See [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/components/client-only) for more.

> The  component renders its slot only in client-side.

Comment: Thanks, but as the content is relevant for SEO I don't want to render it client only